# actionRegion makes my labels disappear

Tags: action, visualforce

The question is quite simple, yet, I'm till' now unable to answer it myself. Is there any solution to stop my label from a selectRadio/selectList/anything from disappearing everytime I use action region? I need to use it due to having required fields whenever one of these radio values is changed but it is breaking my design because it not only does it erase my "label" field but it also moves its location to the left like  a "margin-left: 0".

```
               <apex:pageBlockSection id="Info" title="Some Information" columns="2">
               <apex:actionRegion >
                   <apex:selectRadio id="taxType" label="Why does this disappear?" value="{!answer}">
                       <apex:selectOptions value="{!itemsAnswer}"/>
                       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="Info" status="status"/>
                   </apex:selectRadio>                       
               </apex:actionRegion>
               <apex:outputLabel >Is the Tax paid at the same time as the Cost?</apex:outputLabel>
               </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try wrapping an output panel and Render the panel on change